# Tomcat change port to 80 on Fedora

Tags: tomcat, port, fedora

i want to change Tomcat port from 8080 to 80.

I already changed connector to port 80 in server.xml

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Opened firewall port 80 by firewallid.
Uninstall apachectl too.
Ofcourse after that i restart tomcat, even reboot server.

I'm using Fedora 23 and Tomcat 8.0.38.

When i changed port back to 8080 its work fine on 80 page not found.
Anyone know any reason why its still doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

*NIX won't let non-root users bind to ports below 1024. Running Tomcat as root is an awful idea. Therefore, you will not be able to set Tomcat's `<Connector>` port to 80 without some additional work.

There is a page on the Tomcat wiki that describes [how to use port 80 without root privileges](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_to_run_Tomcat_without_root_privileges.3F). Have a look at that.